# Notice: Undefined Index when checked inside function

Tags: php

Here is the function:

```
function is_set($var, $placeholder = null){
    if(isset($var)){
        return $var;
    } else {
        return $placeholder;
    }
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    is_set($_POST['freq'], '');
}
```

It returns "**Notice: Undefined index: freq in...** "

While this code works well:

```
echo isset($_POST['freq']) ? $_POST['freq'] : '';
```

Why is that??

Comment: Because you'tr trying to pass the _value_ of `$_POST['freq']` when you call the function while `$_POST['freq']` doesn't exist. In PHP 7, you can simply do this: `echo $_POST['freq'] ?? 'fallback value';`

Comment: Hails Magnus. Thanks but... doesn't "does not exist" mean the same as 
"not set"  in this case?

 I call the function when submit button is clicked. So the function is supposed to check if $_POST['something'] is set...if so - return, if not  -return false.

Comment: You can do it so: `function is_set($var, $placeholder = null){ return isset($_POST[$var]) ? $_POST[$var] : $placeholder; }  is_set('freq', '');`

Comment: @splash58 - thanks. but I'd like to understand what's wrong with my function.  I am here not for the solution (for which I am grateful) -  but rather - to understand why is that so??? Magnus mentioned above why but I don't get how that is possible...

Comment: @Rossitten The problem is when you are calling this function like this `is_set($_POST['freq'], '');`, at this time you are sending `$_POST['freq']` as a parameter to the function and at that moment `freq` index is not defined.

Comment: There is a distinction between "not exist" and "not set". If the array `$_POST` doesn't have a key called `'some-key'`, it does not exist. Trying to access it in anyway will throw the error you'r getting. `isset()` doesn't just check if the key exists, but if it _does_ exist, then it also checks that the value isn't `null`. So your problem is that the key simply _doesn't exist_ and thus, you get the error. Btw. the error isn't in your function, it's when you're trying to access a non-existing index in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Error is while call function with undefined variable if 'freq'` it not sent by post request. but using isset is not function call - it's language construction

Comment: got it ! Thanks a lot. damn. feeling ashamed as this is supposed to be a simple thing but somehow I have overlooked that. (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `print_r($_POST);`and check variable you trying to access is available.
you are tryin g to pass `$_POST['freq'])` for the validation before checking whether the variable exists.
exception triggers when your execution hits `is_set($_POST['freq']);` without poast parameter 'freq' .
Try some thing like

```
    if(!empty($_POST['freq'])){
        is_set($_POST['freq']);
    }
```

or pass whole `$_POST` to is_set function and validate variable there.

Comment: when you are accessing $_POST['freq']  , you are accessing undefined variable. you can`t access that before you check it`s existence. you have to either check the whole $_POST variable in is_set function or you have to check the existence of variable and call is_set function.